# Android alsa snd_pcm_open default no such file o directory

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, alsa, baresip

I try to implement baresip for Android, it uses custom `alsa` module for control audio devices.

This module uses this code for open device handler:

```
err = snd_pcm_open(&st->write, device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
```

I tried to pass 'default', 'plug:hw:0,0', 'hw:0,0', 'hw:00,0' into this function. All results return error -2, that means no such file.

I have two question. Is it any possibility to pass some string into this function for handling audio device correct? And in generally, is it real to interact with audio devices directly from jni using this function?

Thank everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that ALSA is supported by Android.
The ALSA api is not available for native Android code (NDK)

for Android you should use the "opensles" module, which provide
an Audio-driver to the native interface.

Baresip supports multiple audio-drivers, for example "alsa" module for Linux
or "opensles" for Android NDK. Please see here for details about the opensles
module:

http://www.creytiv.com/doxygen/baresip-dox/html/opensles_8c.html

Comment: I think you wrong. Android use ALSA driver for audio device communicating, ref http://source.android.com/devices/audio.html.

Comment: Using it **internally** and making it available to developers are two entirely different things.  The difference being in permissions for the device file, and to a lesser extent stable versioning.

Comment: @busylee `"You [Android system manufacturer - V.S.] can choose to use ALSA, OSS, or a custom driver"`. Which means ALSA is not guaranteed to work across devices, though it might on some.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ALSA in Android only on rooted devices.

If you want to play audio from your native code on a stock device, you have at least two choices:

1. Use the official stable API: `OpenSL ES` (this requires Android version 2.3+)
2. There is a native `OpenAL` implementation for Android that uses JNI to call the Java `AudioTrack`: https://github.com/AerialX/openal-soft-android (this will work on Android version 2.1+)

I would recommend using `OpenAL` only if you have the existing code, which needs to be ported to Android, or, for some reason, you have to support Android version 2.1. In other cases `OpenSL ES` is the right choice.

Comment: Do you know maybe, is any function like snd_pcm_writei in OpenAL implementation?

Comment: No, OpenAL was differently. Check out ``alBufferData()`` and the manual: http://open-activewrl.sourceforge.net/data/OpenAL_PGuide.pdf

Comment: is it real to use Open AL on not rooted revices?

Comment: @busylee: Yes. This OpenAL implementation runs on stock devices, starting from Android version 2.1+